httpd doesn't start with config file from windows network share
Problem: httpd.exe (2.4.62 64bit) doesn't start if config located on network smb share. (ex. \server\folder\httpd.conf)
How to re-play: Get zip archive with httpd for Windows. Use standard settings and add below a string with include to httpd.conf
Include "//DESKTOP-C70CLDM/nomad/conf/test.conf"

Start httpd with command from local user.
PS C:\Apache24\bin> .\httpd.exe -e trace8


[Tue Aug 20 15:21:40.989362 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module actions_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_actions.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:40.990361 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module alias_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_alias.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:40.992360 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module allowmethods_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_allowmethods.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:40.994357 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module asis_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_asis.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:40.995369 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module auth_basic_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:40.996363 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authn_core_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authn_core.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:40.996363 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authn_file_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authn_file.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:40.998365 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_core_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authz_core.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:40.999360 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_groupfile_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.000368 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_host_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authz_host.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.001372 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_user_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authz_user.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.002361 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module autoindex_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_autoindex.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.003371 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module cgi_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_cgi.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.004365 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module dir_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_dir.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.005361 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module env_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_env.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.006366 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module include_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_include.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.007368 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module isapi_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_isapi.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.008365 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module log_config_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_log_config.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.009367 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module mime_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_mime.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.011399 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module negotiation_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_negotiation.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.012387 2024] [so:debug] [pid 11532:tid 424] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module setenvif_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_setenvif.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.015387 2024] [core:error] [pid 11532:tid 424] (13)Permission denied: AH10504: ap_filepath_merge: UNC path //DESKTOP-C70CLDM/nomad/conf/test.conf not allowed by UNCList
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 538 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Invalid Include path //DESKTOP-C70CLDM/nomad/conf/test.conf

Add UNCList directive to config before use this include
UNCList DESKTOP-C70CLDM


[Tue Aug 20 15:21:41.015387 2024] [core:error] [pid 11532:tid 424] (13)Permission denied: AH10504: ap_filepath_merge: UNC path //DESKTOP-C70CLDM/nomad/conf/test.conf not allowed by UNCList
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 538 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Invalid Include path //DESKTOP-C70CLDM/nomad/conf/test.conf

Add UNCList with -C directive
.\httpd.exe -e trace8 -C "UNCList DESKTOP-C70CLDM"


[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.171192 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module actions_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_actions.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.172195 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module alias_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_alias.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.173203 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module allowmethods_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_allowmethods.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.174206 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module asis_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_asis.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.175196 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module auth_basic_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.175196 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authn_core_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authn_core.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.176195 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authn_file_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authn_file.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.177198 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_core_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authz_core.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.177198 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_groupfile_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.178197 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_host_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authz_host.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.179194 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module authz_user_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_authz_user.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.180193 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module autoindex_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_autoindex.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.180193 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module cgi_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_cgi.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.181203 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module dir_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_dir.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.182192 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module env_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_env.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.182192 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module include_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_include.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.184201 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module isapi_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_isapi.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.186194 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module log_config_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_log_config.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.186194 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module mime_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_mime.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.187195 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module negotiation_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_negotiation.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.188195 2024] [so:debug] [pid 4136:tid 476] mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module setenvif_module from C:/Apache24/modules/mod_setenvif.so
[Tue Aug 20 15:22:01.188195 2024] [core:error] [pid 4136:tid 476] (13)Permission denied: AH10504: ap_filepath_merge: UNC path //DESKTOP-C70CLDM/nomad/conf/test.conf not allowed by UNCList
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 538 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Invalid Include path //DESKTOP-C70CLDM/nomad/conf/test.conf

Same errors on Windows Server 2019 and Windows Pro 10 systems
In the httpd 2.4.55 everything starts correct.

It is a bug.
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69313
I think will be fix on next releases
